# Is it possible to have the round robin logic in the sharePoint list 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, designer-workflow

Is it possible to have the round robin logic in the sharePoint list?
I have two lists in SharePoint 2010. In List A i have Assigned to field column(people or user group). In List B i have two fields Name and Email id column and In LIST B only five items. If the user add the first item in the LIST A, first e-mail id of the list B should be added in the Assigned to field of LIST A. If the user add the second item in the List A, second  e-mail id of the list B should be added in the Assigned to field of List A. If the user add the third item in the List A, third  e-mail id of the list B should be added in the Assigned to field of List A. If the user add the Fourth item in the List A, Fourth  e-mail id of the list B should be added in the Assigned to field of List A. If the user add the fifth item in the List A, fifth  e-mail id of the list B should be added in the Assigned to field of List A.

If the user add the sixth  item in the List A, first  e-mail id of the list B should be added in the Assigned to field of List A. 
Like wise it will continue.

Is it possible to achieve by workflow or event receiver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible. for this kind of application you have to use Event Receiver which get the total number of item added in LIST A and module by 5.

e.g.:- LIST A Items Count = 6. then if(Count%5 == 1) then Write the Logic to add Email of LIST B in LIST A item, and repeat for all condition(from 1 to 5).

you can use **Item Added Event Receiver**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is it possible to do with custom workflow action.

Comment: Yes It is Possible. It may work same as Item Added Event

Comment: Thanks. I am new to creating Custom work Flow. Is there any sample provided for creating workflow.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231574.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615449.aspx

Comment: This are Link from where you may learn to create custom workflow